# flickering of popup window

Tags: c#

below is my code which closes popup window on page load also i want to show the user a message box plz login well my popup window gets close but it flickers on the screen is there any way to prevent to do that.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script>");

sb.Append("window.close();");

sb.Append("</script");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "test", sb.ToString(), false);

MessageBox.Show("Please Sign In first...", "Login Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense. You're calling `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, so evidently you're using ASP.NET WebForms. But you're also trying to call `MessageBox.Show` (looks like the WinForms version). You had to go out of your way to use both those frameworks from the same code base, and there's a reason for that: they're not meant to work together.

If you're using ASP.NET, that means your C# code is running as a Windows service on the Web server machine. That means that, if a user visits your Web site, you'll try to show a dialog box *on the server machine* (which is in some locked server room somewhere). The visitor to your site won't see a thing on their computer. Actually, since IIS runs as a non-interactive service, I think the call to `MessageBox.Show` will simply be ignored.

The only code that will run on the visitor's machine is the HTML and JavaScript produced by your ASP.NET page. If you want to show a dialog box to the user, you need to use JavaScript. The simplest way is by calling [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.alert).

Comment: In the best case scenario it is ignored. Worst case, it pops up a message box that can never be acknowledged, effectively hanging the system. Avoid `MessageBox.Show` at all costs in anything but a desktop client application.